# Plot bar showing the count of the value of a certain column at descending order?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Given a data frame as following:

```
V1           V2
a            089
a            065
a            012
b            101
b            110
```

Now I'd like to plot a bar, with the count of the value in the first column `V1` as y-axis and it should be a descending order.

I have tried :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(reorder(V1,..count..), y = ..count..) ) +geom_bar(stat = "count")
```

but failed and a warning generated:

```
Warning messages:
1: In min(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(diff(sort(x))) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning  Inf
4: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
5: Computation failed in `stat_count()`:
arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

I have also tried to change the `stat = "bin"` but it didn't work neither.
Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: fyi, this is not an histogram you're trying to plot, it's a bar graph.

Comment: @MLavoie Thanks for reminder. I have changed the title.

Comment: @MLavoie it's a histogram

Comment: @mtoto so you mean geom_bar() is an histogram? and he even change his title!

Comment: he's trying to use `geom_bar` to generate histogram, which is incorrect.

Comment: we're saying the same thing but differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you need your histogram in descending order, you need to change the levels of `V1` first:

```
df$V1 <- factor(df$V1, levels = names(sort(table(df$V1), decreasing = TRUE)))
```

Then we can use

```
library(ggplot2)

# with qplot
qplot(df$V1, geom="histogram") 

# with ggplot
ggplot(df, aes(V1)) + geom_histogram()
```

[image]

Comment: But seems that using qplot can not enable me to customize x-axis?

Comment: I want to change the font size and make it perpendicular to the x-axis

Comment: @moto This is what I used at first. But the x-axis is not at a proper order.

Answer (score 0):

Your code suggest that you're trying to plot a barchart and not a histogram. Asuming that you are indeed looking for a barchart try `stat="identity`(otherwise take a look at `geom_histogram`)

`ggplot(data = df, aes(reorder(V1,V2), y = V2) ) +geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Is this what you are looking for?

[image]

Comment: use `reorder(V1, -V2)` if you want descending order

Comment: Thanks for reply. But the order in my requirement is according to the number of V1 value but V2. Actually, you can ignore V2.